# WebAPI Autorize Authentication Required Popup

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

How to disable Authentication Required pop up when Webapi responding with status code 401 ?

---

[image]

---

that's my webapi config

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(Startup.OAuthOptions.AuthenticationType));

        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        //config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried something? Can you show some code?

Comment: O yes, I'm trying all day without success :(

Comment: The popup is a browser behavior. In case you don't want it, I guess you might have to implement the not authorized in a custom way, instead of returning 401, return another code

Comment: It is indeed browser behavior, caused specifically by the `WWW-Authenticate` header... most browsers automatically prompt for Basic Auth when they see that header, so the key will be figuring out how to remove that header...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to `IIS Manager > Authentication > Basic Authentication` and make sure it's set to `Disabled`.

Comment: that was very good tip, I'm using iis express so I've have to change basicAuthentication to false in my applicationhost.config